# Type inference for (ignoring) method parameters in order to select a MethodInfo

Tags: c#, type-inference

We are creating a configuration API for some of our internal projects. The API is replacing an attribute-based configuration. The new API involves specifying methods within a class along with the options that go with it.

```
public static class Configuration<T> {
    public static void ForMethod(Expression<Action<T>> methodExpression, Options options) { //Option-1
         MethodInfo method = GetMethod(methodExpression);
         // do something with options
    }

    public static void ForMethod<TResult>(Expression<Func<T,TResult>> methodExpression, Options options) { //Option-2
         MethodInfo method = GetMethod(methodExpression);
         // do something with options
   }

   private static MethodInfo GetMethod(Expression expression) {
       // there's other checks done, but this is what it boils down to
       var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression) expression.Body;
       return methodCall.Method;
   }
}

class MyClass {
   void MyMethod() { ... }
}

Configuration<MyClass>.ForMethod(x => x.MyMethod(), ... );
```

This is great except for when the methods themselves have parameters. IE

```
class MyClass2 {
   void MyMethod2(int x) { }
   int SomeOtherMethod(int x) { return x*x; }
}
```

These can be handled by expanding the configuration class like:

```
public static void ForMethod<TResult, TIn>(Expression<Func<T,TIn,TResult>> methodExpression, ...) { //Option-3
}
// and then called: 
Configuation<MyClass2>.ForMethod<int,int>((x,y) => x.SomeOtherMethod(y), ...);
```

As more parameters get added it becomes a bit more clumsy. Technically we don't care about the parameters themselves, so long as we select the correct method. We *could* get around this by simply specifying everything as Option-1 (since we can also ignore the return type and specify everything as Actions) and just specifying the parameters using the `default` keyword, ie:

`Configuration<MyClass2>.ForMethod(x => x.SomeOtherMethod(default(int)), ...)`

However, this gets quite ugly.

**Is there any way with type inference (or some other magic) to select the appropriate method without needing to explicitly state the parameter types?** My hope would be something like this (although this do not work)

`Configuration<MyClass2>.ForMethod((x,y) => x.SomeOtherMethod(y), ...) // Option 3 with return type and type of input inferred`

or even

`Configuration<MyClass2>.ForMethod((x,y) => x.SomeOtherMethod, ...) // Option 3 with return type and input 1 inferred + as method group`

My gut tells me that this is not possible as I haven't been able to find any way around this online. My hope is that perhaps with a combination of extension methods and type inference this *could* be made possible, but I'm having difficulty finding anything that compiles. Is this even possible?

Comment: Anecdotally Moq uses special static methods such that you pass parameters like `It.Is<int>()` which is a bit more readable than `default(int)`. The fact that they do it like this is an indication (though not a guarantee) that this might be the best way of doing it. To deal with overload resolution I would think you will have to pass the parameter types somehow though...