# UrlHelper.Action without hard-coded strings for controllerName and controllerAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like to create a convenient helper method which helps construct an URL from the given controller type and the action/method on that controller. In [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-2.2) there is a `IUrlHelper.Action(string actionName, string controllerName)` method that does the same thing.

But, instead of this: `UrlHelper.Action("MyAction", "MyController")`

I'd like to use: `UrlHelper.Action<MyController>(c => c.MyAction)`

Now, I've only partially managed to solve this problem, which allows me to do something like this: `UrlHelper.Action<MyController>(c => c.MyAction())` (note the parenthesis after the action name) using the following code:

```
    public static string ActionFor<TController>(this IUrlHelper source, Expression<Func<TController, object>> memberExpression) where TController : Controller
    {
        if (!(memberExpression.Body is MemberExpression body)) throw new ArgumentException($"Expression must be a {typeof(MemberExpression).Name}.", nameof(memberExpression));

        return source.Action(body.Member.Name, typeof(TController).RemoveControllerSufix());
    }
```

but I don't know how to tell the compiler that I'd like that `memberExpression` parameter to accept a method group (or similar), so I could write the action name without parenthesis.

P.S. We can also do something like: `UrlHelper.Action<MyController>(nameof(MyController.MyAction))` which also avoids hard-coding of strings, but still duplicates the controller type, that would be great to avoid, too.

I think I saw a post by Jon Skeet somewhere on SO, related to something similar, but I just can't find it now...

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back. I swear it originally had an answer on it.. Either way the sentiment seemed not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41223581/491907

Answer (score 0):

Getting the name of the method group is a bit fiddly. This is how it works (tested in dotnet6/C#10.0).

Call to get the name of the method group:

```
var name = GetMethodGroupName<Foo>(f => f.Bar);
// name: "Bar"
```

Method with pattern matching

```
private static string GetMethodGroupName<TController>(Expression<Func<TController, object>> memberExpression)
{
    if (memberExpression.Body is UnaryExpression
        { Operand: MethodCallExpression
            { Object: ConstantExpression
                { Value: MethodInfo me } } })
        return me.Name;

    throw new ArgumentException(
        "expression does not look like a method group.", 
        nameof(memberExpression));
}
```

... or alternatively with concatinaded checks ...

```
private static string GetMethodGroupName<TController>(Expression<Func<TController, object>> memberExpression)
{
    if (memberExpression.Body is UnaryExpression ue)
        if (ue.Operand is  MethodCallExpression mce)
            if (mce.Object is ConstantExpression ce)
                if (ce.Value is MethodInfo me)
                    return me.Name;

    throw new ArgumentException(
        "expression does not look like a method group.", 
        nameof(memberExpression));
}
```